# Get the size of a remote file from terminal

Tags: wget, curl

I want to download a file from a server, but before doing so I would like to know the actual file size. I know that wget will display the filesize when the download is started, but this actually starts the download process also.

How can I just know the filesize of a remote file on an http server?

Comment: would this suffice: `size_remote=$(curl -sI "http://www.example.com/testfile.bin" | awk '/Content-Length/ { print $2 }')` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try typing:

```
wget --spider
```

It gives for example *134K*:

```
$ wget --spider "https://askubuntu.com/questions/389910/get-the-size-of-a-remote-file-from-terminal/389920#389920"
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2019-09-27 20:34:46--  https://askubuntu.com/questions/389910/get-the-size-of-a-remote-file-from-terminal/389920
Resolving askubuntu.com (askubuntu.com)... 151.101.193.69, 151.101.129.69, 151.101.65.69, ...
Connecting to askubuntu.com (askubuntu.com)|151.101.193.69|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 136873 (134K) [text/html]
Remote file exists and could contain further links,
but recursion is disabled -- not retrieving.
```

Comment: Solves my problem :)

Comment: Similar to [`curl --head URI`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl), it fetches only the http req header (HEAD method)